# Ajax submit in hidden form validation not executed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, jquery-validate

I have the following situation:

I have a button. When clicked, a hidden form and submit button appears. The form is validated using the jQuery Validation plugin. In the submit handler, I want to submit the form using Ajax. My problem is, the code I wrote in the submit handler does not seem to execute.

**HTML page:**

```
<div class='col-md-9'>
    <div class='media-body'>
        <form id='accountForm'>
            <div class='input-group'>
                <div class='input-group-addon'>
                    First name:
                </div>
                <input class='form-control' type='text' name='firstName'>
            </div>
            <!--- some more inputs --->
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<div class='col-md-3'>
    <div class='btn-group btn-group-vertical'>
        <!--- some buttons --->
        <button id='saveButton' class='btn' type='submit' form='accountForm'>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript file:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#accountForm').hide();
    $('#saveButton').hide();

    $('#editInfoButton').on('click', function() {
        $('#accountForm').show();
        $('#saveButton').show();
    });

    $('#accountForm').validate({
        rules: //some rules
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/account/profile',
                data: $(form).serialize(),
                success: function(data, status, jqXHR) {
                    //some stuff
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

When I click on the submit button, there is no `POST`-request send to `/account/profile` but a `GET`-request to `/account?firstName=...`. I don't really understand why this isn't working.

Comment: Stupid question probably: what happens if you state POST in your form tag?

The type for AJAX request is POST, however the form still has no action/method defined so the form execution would still follow those.

Comment: Well I'll be damned.. Now it works. Just spend an hour on this. Thank you, kind sir!

Comment: @charlietfl But I'm not using Angular...

Comment: I still don't see a `submit` button ***inside*** the `form` container.  What triggers this?

Comment: That's because the `saveButton` has the attribute `form='accountForm'`

Comment: FYI and FWIW, the `form` attribute is not supported in all browsers incl Explorer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just so this question has a decent answer:

My situation, described in the question, was solved by the comment of user [Jack hardcastle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4141176/jack-hardcastle).

> Stupid question probably: what happens if you state POST in your form tag? The type for AJAX request is POST, however the form still has no action/method defined so the form execution would still follow those.

It should be noted, as was by [Sparky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/594235/sparky), that the `form` attribute is not supported by all browsers incl. IE.